# Enviar email outlook usando Flask

Tags: python, email, flask

Estou tentando criar um código que manda email outlook com flask, mas por algum motivo não vai, testei com gmail, tbm não está indo

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'seuemail@.com
app.config['Mail_PASSWORD'] = '******'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
app.config['MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENT'] = False

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    msg = Message('hello', sender='seuemail@.com', recipients=['emailfulano@.com'])
    return 'Message Sent'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

No código enviado só está a ser criada a mensagem a enviar, e fica a falta o processo de envio. Está a falta a linha que vai fazer o envio do e-mail.

```
mail.send(msg)
```

A função deverá ficar da seguinte forma

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    msg = Message('hello', sender='seuemail@.com', recipients=['emailfulano@.com'])
    mail.send(msg)
    return 'Message Sent'
```